# How do I check if I connected to the server? Python Sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, network-programming

I haven't tested that yet, but if the connection will not be executed, will this last sentence be printed?

```
def connect_to():
    print(f"[*] Connecting to {receiver_ip}:{receiver_port}")
    socket.connect((receiver_ip, receiver_port))
    print(f"[+] Connected")
```

How can I check if I connected properly and make a proper if statement?

Comment: No it will not be printed . Use try and except block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a socket fails to connect, it will raise a `socket.error` exception. You can catch that specific error using some [error handling techniques](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) in Python.

```py
import socket


def connect(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket()

    try:
        print(f"Connecting to {ip}:{port}")
        s.connect((ip, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(f"Failed to connect: {msg}")
    else:
        print(f"Successfully connected to {ip}:{port}")
```

> How can I check if I connected properly and make a proper if statement?

The `except` block will be executed if the specified error is caught in the try block. On the other hand, the `else` block will be executed when no errors were raised or handled. You can view the `except` block as "if error" and the `else` block as "if not error".

Alternatively, you can catch an error and re-raise it with your custom message.

```py
import socket


def connect(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket()

    try:
        print(f"Connecting to {ip}:{port}")
        s.connect((ip, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        raise socket.error(f"Failed to connect: {msg}")

    print(f"Successfully connected to {ip}:{port}")
```

By catching and re-raising, you don't have to use the `else` block anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use try except to catch the errors and if the connection is successful

Comment: Do I need to catch some exceptions that connect() function returns?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).